# Set LZMA compression level via tar

Tags: shell, debian, tar

How can I set the compression level for this command?

```
tar --lzma -cf files/compressed/lzma/archive.lzma -C files/original/ .
```

With `--bzip` I just use:

```
BZIP2=-9 tar --bzip2 -cf files/compressed/bzip2//archive.tar.bz2 -C files/original/ .
```

but with the `--lzma` option `LZMA=-9` doesn't work.

Is this enviroment variable name incorrect? Where can I get the correct variable name?

Comment: Why duplicate? I did not ask how to set compress setting the XZ but lzma... I do not want write command by pipelines but only tar...

Comment: Retracted it, yours that that have the same answer, so I firstly think it duplicated.

Comment: @cuonglm You was right is a duplicate - sorry. But i don't understand in `tar --help` is parameter `--xz` and `--lzma` with description `filter the archive through xz` they are not different comprimation methods?

Comment: @LajdákMarek `xz` can compress and decompress `lzma` files in most cases. See `man xz` for details...

Answer (score 4):

If your version of `tar` uses `xz` for `--lzma` (which is likely, even Debian 6 used that), you can use the `XZ_OPT` variable:

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar --lzma ...
```